# I want to know how the map this function works in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
bools :: Int -> [[Bool]]
bools 0 = [[]]
bools n = map (False:) bss ++ map (True:) bss
    where bss = bools (n-1)
```

Enter the following and the result is...

```
bools 2
```

```
[[False,False],[False,True],[True,False],[True,True]]
```

I'm not sure what the '(False :)' and '(True :)' means in this function.

And I'm not sure why the results come out like that.

There is no article explaining Haskell in detail, so ask a question here.

Thanks for answering my problem.

Comment: It prepends a list with `True` and `False` respectively`.

Answer (score 1):

The "cons" function `(:)` is one of the data constructors of a list. Haskell implements lists like a linked list. A list has two data constructors:

1. the empty list `[]`; and
2. the [*cons* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) that takes an element which is the *head* of the list, and another list of elements which is the *tail* of the list.

So a list like `[1,4,2]` is the "short form" of `1 : (4 : (2 : []))`, or in canonical form `(:) 1 ((:) 4 ((:) 2 []))`.

With the [*section of an infix operator* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), we can write functions like `(1 :)` which is short for `(:) 1`.

The `(False :)` expression is thus short for `(:) False`. It is a function that takes a list of `Bool`s, and returns a list that starts with `False` followed by the elements of the given list. `(True :)` on the other hand will prepend the list with `True`.

If you thus call `bools 2`, then this will evaluate to:

```
bools 2 = map (False :) bss ++ map (True :) bss
    where bss = bools 1
```

here `bools 1` will evaluate to:

```
bools 1 = map (False :) bss ++ map (True :) bss
    where bss = bools 0
```

and the first clause of the `bools` function specifies that `bools 0 = [[]]`, so that means that `bools1` is:

```
bools 1 = map (False :) [[]] ++ map (True :) [[]]
```

this is thus equal to:

```
bools 1 = [[False]] ++ [[True]]
```

and thus:

```
bools 1 = [[False], [True]]
```

for `bools 2`, we thus obtain:

```
bools 2 = map (False :) [[False], [True]] ++ map (True :) [[False], [True]]
```

we thus prepend `False` to the lists in the `map (False :)` expression, and we prepend `True` to the lists in the `map (True :)` expression:

```
bools 2 = [[False, False], [False, True]] ++ [[True, False], [True, True]]
```

which is thus equal to:

```
bools 2 = [[False, False], [False, True], [True, False], [True, True]]
```